# Does subscribe("newBlockHeader",...) consistently provide the header of the most recent block?

Tags: web3js

Assuming we are trying the blow code that subscribes to incoming block headers and returns the header of the i-th block in the ledger, triggering the execution of the callback function in then(). If the callback function takes an extended period such that the (i+1)-th and (i+2)-th blocks are added to the ledger, will the subscriber receive the header of the (i+1)-th or (i+2)-th block for subscription? Does it consistently provide the header of the most recent block?

```
web3.eth.subscribe("newBlockHeaders",function(error,result){
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }else{
        console.info("Result:\n"+result);
    }
}).then(function(subscription){
    subscription.on("data",function(blockHeader){
...
       })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

While `subscribe("newBlockHeaders",...)` usually delivers the latest block header, there's a nuance. You're guaranteed the latest within a single callback, but network delays, lengthy callback processing, or node syncing can cause slight overall delays.

So, while you get the most recent header available when the callback runs, it might be a bit different from the absolute newest if other blocks were mined.

Comment: So you are saying that it is possible `subscribe()` miss some block header, true?